# Prove that $f'(x)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ open. If $f: U \to \mathbb{R}$ attains a relative maximum ( or minimum) in the point $x \in U$, and $f$ is differentiable in point $x$, then $f'(x)=0$.

Comment: I believe you may be right. But it's relative max, not max relative, at least for most writers of texts.

Comment: feel free to correct my text ... i am Brazilian and not the domino english

Comment: I agree--I was being a bit picky. It seems I like to see the right terminology. But I knew what you meant, and made a reply about the question in one of the "answers".

Answer (score 1):

This may be an approach: Take your function and create $n$ one variable functions by restricting $f$ to the coordinat axes near $x$. Apply the one variable result to each. Now you have all the partial derivatives zero; I seem to recall that "differentiable" in $n$ space implies the existence of a good tangent plane approximation to $f$, and from that and the zero partials, you might be able to get $f'(x)=0.$

If only I remembered my courses better.

Comment: My God, where are the symbols...ok i will study your idea..thanks

Comment: I didn't put extra notation in my answer, but I meant that for the point x we use the lines that are *parallel* to the usual axes in n space, and pass through point x. To symbolize that would not be difficult, but it would take a lot of time/effort for me, not being much of an expert at LaTex.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you know this result is valid for one dimensional functions. So you can proceed like this:

Consider the set $U_{d}=\{x+td:t\in (-\epsilon,\epsilon)\}$ where $\epsilon$ is a small number and $d\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Consider the  restriction of $f$ to $U_{d}$; lets denote it by $f_{d}$.

Now, $f_{d}$ is a function of one variable and attains its maximum or minimum in $x$. Hence $f'_{d}(0)=0$, or equivalent $f'(x)d=0$. As $d$ is any point in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, then you have $f'(x)=0$.

Ps: As you are brazilian, you can take a look in Elon's first book of analysis to see the proof for the case one dimensional.